# React accessing state in nested components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

React newbie here. I'm building a simple voting app and have it all just about working but have one remaining item. In the code below, I'm getting an 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined at Votes' error. I'm sure this is because my Votes function is outside the scope of the array items but I don't know how to code this to fix it. Help appreciated.

```
class Ratings extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            votes: 0
        };
        this.add = this.add.bind(this);
        this.subtract = this.subtract.bind(this);
        this.reset = this.reset.bind(this);
    }
    add(event){
        this.setState ({
            votes: this.state.votes + 1
        })
    }
    subtract(event){
        this.setState ({
            votes: this.state.votes - 1
        })
    }
    reset(event){
        this.setState ({
            votes: 0
        })
    }
    render () {
        this.movies = this.props.list.map(x => {
            return (
                <div key={x.id} className="movierater">
                <MoviePoster poster={x.img}/>
                <h1 className="title">{x.name}</h1>
                    <div className="votewrapper">
                        <button onClick={this.add}><i className="votebutton fa fa-thumbs-o-up" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                        <Votes />
                        <button onClick={this.subtract}><i className="votebutton fa fa-thumbs-o-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                    </div>
                <button onClick={this.reset} className="reset">Reset</button>
                </div>
            )
        });
        return (
            <div>
                {this.movies}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

function MoviePoster(props) {
    return (
        <img src={props.poster} alt="Movie Poster" className="poster"/>
    );
}

function Votes(props) {
    return (
        <h2>Votes: {this.state.votes}</h2>
    );
}

var movieposters = [
    {id: 1, img:"http://www.impawards.com/2017/posters/med_alien_covenant_ver4.jpg", name: "Alien Covenant"},
    {id: 2, img:"http://www.impawards.com/2017/posters/med_atomic_blonde_ver4.jpg", name: "Atomic Blonde"},
    {id: 3, img:"http://www.impawards.com/2017/posters/med_easy_living_ver3.jpg", name: "Easy Living"},
    {id: 4, img:"http://www.impawards.com/2017/posters/med_once_upon_a_time_in_venice_ver3.jpg", name: "Once Upon a Time in Venice"},
    {id: 5, img:"http://www.impawards.com/2017/posters/med_scorched_earth.jpg", name: "Scorched Earth"},
    {id: 6, img:"http://www.impawards.com/2017/posters/med_underworld_blood_wars_ver9.jpg", name: "Underworld: Blood Wars"},
    {id: 7, img:"http://www.impawards.com/2017/posters/med_void.jpg", name: "The Void"},
    {id: 8, img:"http://www.impawards.com/2017/posters/med_war_for_the_planet_of_the_apes.jpg", name: "War for the Planet of the Apes"},
]


ReactDOM.render(
    <Ratings list={movieposters} />,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Comment: You should pass a lambda to `setState()`.

Comment: Although I agree where passing a callback to `setState()` is preferred than an object.  This won't solve his problem.

Answer (score 3):

You have to do just like you are doing in `MoviePoster`. Pass a prop to `Votes` like this

```
<Votes votes={this.state.votes} />
```

And then in your `Votes` function use that prop like this

```
function Votes(props) {
    return (
        <h2>Votes: {props.votes}</h2>
    );
}
```

Comment: That's very similar to what I had tried myself. The problem is that when I click an up or down button, it updates the votes state for every item in the array, and not just the one clicked.

Answer (score 1):

pass votes down as props to your votes component
`<Votes votes={this.state.votes} />`

and then access the votes with props rather than state

```
function Votes(props) {
    return (
        <h2>Votes: {props.votes}</h2>
    );
}
```

Comment: There's no `this` in functional components, though :)

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access the state of the Ratings component inside the Votes functional component. Instead, what you should do is pass the relevant state to the Votes component as a prop:

```
<Votes count={this.state.votes} />
```

And then, in the Votes function:

```
function Votes(props) {
    return (<h2>Votes: {props.count}</h2>);
}
```

As an aside, this is also a perfect opportunity to use [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to improve readability:

```
function Votes({ count }) {
    return (<h2>Votes: {count}</h2>);
}
```

Comment: That's very similar to what I had tried myself. The problem is that when I click an up or down button, it updates the votes state for every item in the array, and not just the one clicked.

Comment: Sounds like you have another question to ask, regarding state management. React doesn't do much to help you manage the state of your app, so you may want to look into something like [Redux](https://redux.js.org/).

Comment: Thx, Nico. I think a React with Redux course is next on my schedule.